# Create unpublished product in Shopify via API

Tags: shopify

In the Shopify Admin each product has a series of checkboxes that allow the user to toggle between `Online store`, `Point of sale`, `Buy button`, and `Mobile app`.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I'm pushing products into the Shopify via the API.

**How can I push a product through the Shopify API as hidden on the web?**

I dived deep and Here are the settings for each configuration:

```
---

Online store ✓
Point of sale
Buy button
Mobile app

published_at: "2016-02-18T17:14:00-05:00",
published_scope: "web",

---

Online store ✓
Point of sale ✓
Buy button
Mobile app

published_at: "2016-02-18T17:14:00-05:00",
published_scope: "global",

---

Online store ✓
Point of sale ✓
Buy button ✓
Mobile app

published_at: "2016-02-18T17:14:00-05:00",
published_scope: "global",

---

Online store ✓
Point of sale ✓
Buy button ✓
Mobile app ✓

published_at: "2016-02-18T17:14:00-05:00",
published_scope: "global",

---

Online store ✓
Point of sale
Buy button ✓
Mobile app ✓

published_at: "2016-02-18T17:14:00-05:00",
published_scope: "web",

---

Online store 
Point of sale
Buy button ✓
Mobile app ✓

published_at: null,
published_scope: "web",

---

Online store 
Point of sale
Buy button
Mobile app

published_at: null,
published_scope: "web",

---
```

My general observations for testing this is as follows.

- No way to detect if a product has `Buy button` or `Mobile app` enabled for a product.
- No way to toggle these fields in the API.
- The `published_scope` property has two options `web` and `global`

Comment: Your observations are right. There's nothing more that can be done, Shopify has been intimated regarding this drawback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide a product on all channels (`web` and `poc`).

Include this in the product request.

```
    "published": false,
    "published_scope": "web",
```

Comment: Still unsure how to toggle for mobile via API.

Comment: `"published" : false` will hide all the product everywhere irrespective of `published_scope`. As mentioned in my earlier comment there is nothing in this matter. More details here - https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/what-is-the-function-of-the-published_scope-field-187190

Comment: Can customer buy unpublished product ?